# End of File Expected

Tags: python, json

This is the json file I am working with. I am new to json and after doing some basic research, I was able to dump a dictionary that I had in it with some sample data as placeholders. When I try to use the file though it says that the End of file expected json[9,1] and I have no idea how to fix this as most of the results that I have found on this topic go way over my head. Thanks

```
{
    "923390702359048212": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}

{
    "462291477964259329": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
{
    "803390252265242634": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
{
    "832041337968263178": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
{
    "824114065445486592": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
```

Comment: Afaik, JSON can't have multiple top-level objects like that. I believe you need to wrap the whole thing in an array/list, and then put comma in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have separate objects in your json file. You need to have this as an array.

```
[{
    "923390702359048212": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},

{
    "462291477964259329": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}]
```

Comment: With this, how would I reference each of the individual pieces of data? The original way I was doing it was jsondata[str(userid)[0]) but now its saying that list indices must be integers or slices, not str which I am not sure how to work around.

Comment: You can add a key to original data. For eg: "somekey": [{"92":[0,0]},{"46":[0,0]}]

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma between bracket section an add a level of bracket

```
{
 {
    "923390702359048212": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},

{
    "462291477964259329": [
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
 }
}
```

Complete all the json like that and it will be okay

Comment: Still says that the end of file is expected and now references the comma instead of the bracket

Comment: @Happyface456 I have edited my post just before you answer it, I forgot to tell you to a a level of braket to contait all the contain. Have you add it?

Comment: Yep and that works now. Thanks